# How to set locale by controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, bots

I want to set locale for change language but my project is not website but it is a Facebook bot which developed through base controller, I want Example  thank.

Comment: Mind to elaborate on the _why_ @SuperStormer? Chatbots (often) work via webhooks, so building an API with a web framework seems reasonable. Projects like [botman](https://botman.io) also support this idea.

Answer (score 0):

The default language for your application is stored in the config/app.php configuration file. Of course, you may modify this value to suit the needs of your application. You may also change the active language at runtime using the setLocale method on the App facade:

```
    Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
        //
    });
```

see more in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#introduction